# Eclipse neon cannot change / color the syntax coloring of jsp scripting elements?

Tags: eclipse, themes, editor, eclipse-neon

I am setting up my new eclipse neon 2.
I am using the dark moonrise theme also: http://guari.github.io/eclipse-ui-theme/

I am trying to change the syntax coloring of the editor in Windows->Preferences etc.

I have already changed most of it coloring and however I have failed to change / enable the syntax coloring of the Web->JSP Files->Editor->Syntax Coloring: Scripting Elements.

The enable checkbox is checked, but also greyed out. I am only able to change the background color, but not the foreground.

[scripting-elements-edit.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXLN0.png)

I mean why does the syntax coloring edit get disabled here and maybe a few other places?
Does anyone know how is this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The foreground colors are dictated by the Syntax Coloring preferences for the relevant page language. Usually, it's Java, so set those on the Syntax Coloring preference page for Java.

Comment: I did changd the syntax color of java.. but no results; see my edited question. --And I needed 10 reps to post 2 links, so here it is: i.stack.imgur.com/QDPoI.png Thx

Comment: No results after closing and reopening the JSP editor?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I restarted eclipse still the same.. re you running neon.2? I can't remember the older versions becoz I didn't do much jsp then...

Comment: I just use the dark theme now rather than moonrise.. oh well.